# Angular 1.2 - ui-router and accessing the parameter outside the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using [UI-Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) to mange my routing on my application.

One item I've hit a snag on it with my menu which is the main view that the controllers will use.

for example I have a home link that should be

> index.htm#/home/3
>
> index.htm#/settings/3

3 is the companyId

but it seems that I can't access it that way. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I could make that work?

Answer (score 1):

Parent states should not be accessing the parameters of child states, but there is a little bit of magic that ui-router provides that might help.  This is [ui-sref-active](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive%3aui-sref-active).  This directive will add css classes to html elements that have a `ui-sref` directive and that state is currently active.  I think this would be sufficient to solve the problem that you have.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go, worst case I'll just use server-side to resolve the issue for me.